# Fetching the current location of the browser and send the data in db using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am doing an silly mistake in getting  the location of the browser and storing using an external ip , ajax and php file.I am getting an error as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I think i am not sending the data properly in the php file, Here is my AJAX function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
      var city_data = val(response.city);
      var region_data = val(response.region);
        data: {city: city_data, region: region_data},
        type: "post",
        url: "test3.php",
        success: function(data){
             alert("Data Saved: " + data);
        }
}, "jsonp");

});
```

and my php file as :

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST))
 {
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("practice");
 error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE); 
 print_r($_POST);
 return;
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $region=$_POST['region'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO location(area,country) VALUES ('$city','$region')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  if($result){
  echo "Work Done.";
   } 
   }
   ?>
```

I used mysql as this is for testing, Please have a look on my codes and let me know where i went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your syntax. You have the body of your callback function mingled with AJAX properties.

Comment: since you are practicing, why dont you adopt PDO right now ? will save you tons if issues later, not to mention that `mysql_*` is deprecated *right now*. Read about **[little bobby](https://xkcd.com/327/)** and SQL injection.

Comment: @DarthJDG Can you write in the answer field where  i did wrong as i am not getting it. Thanks

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Sure ,I will practice with PDO here after , Can you tell me where i went wrong

Comment: Well the `return;` saves you from SQL injections because the SQL will never get executed. `If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in syntax, who say @DarthJDG Add $.ajax to your request

Example that will serve you for your problem

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data){
      var city_data = data.city;
      var region_data = data.region;
      $.ajax({
        data: {city: city_data, region: region_data},
        type: "post",
        url: "test3.php",
        success: function(data){
             alert("Data Saved: " + data);
        }
      })
  })

});
```

Comment: It does solved my error but the data is not getting stored in the database

Comment: You remove  `print_r($_POST); return;` ? and out print  `$sql` execute in mysql client or command line mysql and see which output delivers the command line

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the data object and the success callback. According to the documentation of [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), the first parameter is the url, the second the data-object, the third the callback if the request succeeded and the last one the data type (like `json`, `html` or `xml`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        var city_data = response.city;
        var region_data = response.region;

        $.post("test3.php",
            {
                // data
                city: city_data,
                region: region_data
            },
            function (data) {
                // success
                console.log("data successfully saved.");
            }
        )
    }, "json")
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, I am not getting any error but the data is also not getting stored in the database

Comment: Take a look into the developer tools console. Do you get an error?

Comment: Add the [error controller](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `or die(mysqli_error())` after the `mysqli_query()` function to see if something's wrong with the query.

Comment: Is the script inside the `if(isset($_REQUEST))` reachable? Otherwise try to replace it with `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`.

Comment: I got it what i am looking for . Thank you for the help